# Generic types have different meaning depending on the context. Why?

Tags: java, list, generics, wildcard

Recently I've been studying Generic Types and a little bit of Wildcards. I'm going to illustrate the problem with an example code:

```
    ArrayList<SuperClass> arraySuper = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<SubClass> arraySub = new ArrayList<>();

    arraySuper.add(new SuperClass());
    arraySuper.add(new SubClass());
```

Where SuperClass obviously is the super class of Subclass. In this example **SuperClass in the diamond operator means "SuperClass or its subclasses"**. This is reasonable.
But here:

```
   static void doSomething(ArrayList<SuperClass> idk) {}
```

with

```
    doSomething(arraySuper);
    doSomething(arraySub);   // Compile Error
```

**SuperClass means "only SuperClass and not its subclasses."**

Why is there this difference?
Thanks for all answers.

Comment: "In this example SuperClass in the diamond operator means "SuperClass or its subclasses"" no: it means "infer the type from context". You've already said it's an `ArrayList<Superclass>` on the left, so the compiler takes it to be the same on the right. And since all `Subclass` instances are also instances of `Superclass`, you can add them to a list accepting instances of `Superclass`.

Comment: Oh, are you meaning `<SuperClass>`? That's not the diamond operator: `<>` is the diamond operator. `<SuperClass>` is a type parameter.

Comment: @AndyTurner Sorry, my fault, then I mean the type parameter. But the question remains, why is there a difference?

Comment: @AndyTurner And thanks for your answer!